# I'm unable to link my CSS file to my EJS file

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I can't add my external `main.css` onto my `header.ejs` file.
I set my CSS file as **public** in my `index.js` (my backend Node.js with Express.js server) by using the static code:

`app.use(express.static("public"));`

Then, I linked between the **header** file to the **css** file:

```
<link href="/Backend/Capstone Project - Public API/public/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, nothing of the CSS file renders on the screen (I tried to change the background to blue color as a test).

Here are the full codes:

***main.css:***

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:  blue;
}

h1 {
    color: aqua;
}
```

***index.js***

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";
//import favicon from "serve-favicon";
//import path from "path";
//import { dirname } from "path";
//import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

//const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";

//app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public','images','cup-straw.svg'))); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs")
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
        const result = response.data;
        console.log(result);
        res.render("index.ejs", {drink: result});
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.result);
        res.status(500);
     } 
});



app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

***header.ejs:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/Backend/Capstone Project - Public API/public/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="/Backend/Capstone Project - Public API/public/images/cup-straw.svg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>The Cocktails Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
```

***index.ejs:***

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>

    <h1>Cocktails</h1>
    <br />

<main>


<h2>Your drink:</h2>
<% if (locals.drink) { %>
  <div class="cocktail-box"></div>
  <% drink.drinks.forEach(drinkDetail => { %>
   <li><%= drinkDetail.strDrink %></li>
   <div class="ingr">
   <h3>Ingredients</h3>
   <% for( let i = 1; i < 16; i++ ) { %>
    <% if (drinkDetail['strIngredient' + i] != null) { %>
      <li><%= drinkDetail['strMeasure' + i] %> of <%= drinkDetail['strIngredient' + i] %></li>
    <% } %>
   <% } %>
   </div>
   <div class="ins">
   <h3>Instructions</h3>
   <li><%= drinkDetail.strInstructions %></li>  
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="<%= drinkDetail.strDrinkThumb %>" alt="cocktail"/>
   </div>
  <% }) %>
  </div>
<% } %>
 
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="buttonDrink" id="buttonClick">GET A DRINK</button>
  </form>


</main>

<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

***footer.ejs***

```
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your css file is in your `/public/styles/` directory. Since you have told express to serve static content from the `public` directory that is considered the root of static content so just change the stylesheet `<link>` like so:

```html
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As an aside, to future-proof your app I can see you are creating a `__dirname` function from your commented out code. Using this in combination with `express.static` would look like:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';
const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Hi, I changed it as you mentioned, but still nothing happens... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Did you change to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`. Look in your browser dev tools. Click the Network tab and refresh the page. What does it say for the `style.css` file?

Comment: Yes, I did change it to app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) and the Network tab says about the main.css file that is ok (200).
However, still, nothing renders... Very strange